# Check an entire column to see if text exists. If it does then document it in a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a column to see if a certain series of text exist. If it does, then I want to show which text exists in a range.

I have tried for loop and for each cell commands, but I am not sure what else commands to try.

For throughout the entire column shown below, if AH, DF appears I want to write "AutoCAD Construction Issue Hard Copy" in Range B10, and "Digital Files" in B11. If just "DF, P" appears, I want to write "Digital Files" in Range B10 and Prints in B11. However if all three of them appear (Like how they do in the picture below) I want to write "AutoCAD Construction Issue Hard Copy" in B10. "Digital Files" in B11 and Prints in B12. My problem is, is that whenever I create this list, I want the list to start at B10 and not have a gap in between the list. The order of the list must be AutoCAD Construction Issue Hard Copy,  Digital Files, and Prints.

My code is pasted below:

```
Sub Descriptions()
    Range("A14:A305").ClearContents

    For r = 14 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        On Error Resume Next  'get rid of that... find error and fix/build logic, don't ignore it

        If Range("A1").Value = "30% Design Review" Or Range("A1").Value = "Final Design Review" Then
            If InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "BMC-9") Then
                Cells(r, "E").Value = "Bill of Materials"
                Cells(r, "A").Value = "DF, P"
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "MC-9") Or InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "CSR-9") Or InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "LC-9") Then
                Cells(r, "A").Value = "DF, P"
            End If
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "Construction Submittal" Then
            If InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "BMC-9") Then
                Cells(r, "E").Value = "Bill of Materials"
                Cells(r, "A").Value = "DF, P"
            ElseIf InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "MC-9") Or InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "CSR-9") Or InStr(Cells(r, "B").Value, "LC-9") Then
                Cells(r, "A").Value = "AH, DF"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For r = 14 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(r, "A").Value = "DF, P" Then
            Range("B10").Value = "Digital Files"
            Range("B11").Value = "Prints"
        ElseIf Cells(r, "A").Value = "AH, DF" Then
            Range("B10").Value = "AutoCAD Construction Issue Hard Copy"
            Range("B11").Value = "Digital Files"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

New Edit 04/11/2019

[image]

Comment: Sorry, where's the picture?

Comment: Sorry, I must of forgot to upload that. I posted in the answer portion below.

Comment: That's ok, based on the fact that you answered your own question, I figure you worked out a solution?

Comment: Not just yet. If I have "AH, P" I need it to say "Prints" in the list

Comment: Personally I think a formula approach would be more sustainable/scalable but that's just me.  I'm happy to provide that but I'd need to see a screenshot of your source data.  It's a bit ambiguous at the moment.

Comment: @Skin I added it to edit portion of my question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be confused by what you're asking, but, I think you can achieve this with a formula.

[image]

... as you can see, it's an array formula so when you go to commit it, make sure you press **Shift + Ctrl + Enter**, failure to do so will render it useless.

If it finds your text from within the given range, you'll get a number greater than or equal to 1, from there, you can provide another lookup from another cell to display your text.

So if I try and use your exact scenario, this is what I came up with ...

[image: Example]

To make it easier to understand, you can download the example workbook here ...

[Example Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqqhKGhViAgFnDhPU3uTdgsfxiep)

As I said, I think doing all of this as a formula based approach would make it easier to maintain longer term.  Maybe that's just me though.

I hope that gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub SeachDesc()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("A14:A305")
Range("B10:B12").ClearContents
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value = "DF, P" Then
        Range("B10").Value = "Digital Files"
        Range("B11").Value = "Print(s)"
    ElseIf cel.Value = "AH, DF" Then
        Range("B10").Value = "AutoCAD Construction Issue Hard Copy"
        Range("B11").Value = "Digital Files"
    End If
Next cel
    If Range("B11").Value = "Print(s)" And Range("B12").Value = "Print(s)" Then
        Range("B10").Value = "AutoCAD Construction Issue Hard Copy"
        Range("B11").Value = "Digital Files"
        Range("B12").Value = "Print(s)"
    End If
End Sub
```